# Dynamic way to create a set date based on a range of dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a set date based on a range in order to create a set for visualizations. This is awfully repetitive and not future proof. Does anyone have any ideas on how to simplify this?

```
Select CASE WHEN date BETWEEN '2010-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-07-31 12:59:59'
        THEN '2011-05-31 00:00:00'
    WHEN date BETWEEN '2011-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-07-31 12:59:59'
        THEN '2012-05-31 00:00:00'
    WHEN date BETWEEN '2012-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-07-31 12:59:59'
        THEN '2013-05-31 00:00:00'
    WHEN date BETWEEN '2013-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-07-31 12:59:59'
        THEN '2014-05-31 00:00:00'
    WHEN date BETWEEN '2014-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-07-31 12:59:59'
        THEN '2015-05-31 00:00:00'
    WHEN date BETWEEN '2015-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-07-31 12:59:59'
        THEN '2016-05-31 00:00:00'
    WHEN date BETWEEN '2016-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-07-31 12:59:59'
        THEN '2017-05-31 00:00:00'
    WHEN date BETWEEN '2017-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-07-31 12:59:59'
        THEN '2018-05-31 00:00:00'
    WHEN date BETWEEN '2018-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-07-31 12:59:59'
        THEN '2019-05-31 00:00:00'
    WHEN date BETWEEN '2019-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 12:59:59'
        THEN '2020-05-31 00:00:00'
    END AS modifiedDate,
```

FROM table1

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Date/time functions are notoriously database-specific.

Comment: Also, do a search on extracting date parts to ignore year in your RDBMS that you tag.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What do you mean by the database? Sorry, I'm new to this. It is on MSSQL Server.

Comment: @James, identifying the database (RDBMS system) you are using is done with the "tags" that appear under your question.

Answer (score 0):

You seed to want May 31st based on some strange date arithmetic -- presumably, some sort of fiscal year.

This can all be calculated using date arithmetic.  Without a database tag, it is hard to specify the correct syntax.  But, the idea is:

```
select (date '2011-05-31' +
        (extract(year from date + interval '5 month') - 2011) * interval '1 year'
       )
```

This is expressed in ISO/ANSI SQL, but the idea can be expressed in any database -- although any given database might have other approaches as well.

In SQL Server, this would be:

```
select dateadd(year,
               (extract(year from date + interval '5 month') - 2011),
               '2011-05-31'
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

Got this from another site before you guys answered, which worked perfectly:

```
Case when month(date)>=8 then datefromparts(year(date)+1,5,31) 
        when month(date)<8 then datefromparts(year(date),5,31) 
    end as modifiedDate
```

Thanks for your answers too. Helped me on a couple of other issues I was having.